# Modified Helmholtz for imaginary constant

Tags: partial-differential-equations, greens-function, fundamental-solution

The Green's function for the free space modified Helmholtz equation in two dimensions is
\begin{equation}
\alpha^{2}u - \Delta u = 0,
\end{equation}
with $\alpha^{2}$ real, is $K_{0}$. However, I am looking for the corresponding function for modified Helmholtz with $\alpha^{2}$ being purely imaginary. Can anyone provide me with a reference?