# Non-integer order and non-half-integer order solution to Helmholtz equation

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics, laplacian

**Context**

This question is related to the unsolved questions in [2].

I want to solve the Helmholtz equation in spherical coordinates by separation of variables. It is  typical to see the differential equation written in terms of an integer $n$ as,
$$x^2 \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} + 2x \frac{dy}{dx} + \left(x^2 - n(n + 1)\right) y = 0.$$
Now, I know that,

> ``The two linearly independent solutions to this equation are called the  spherical Bessel functions, and are related to the ordinary Bessel functions $J_n$ and $Y_n$ by
> \begin{align}
> j_n(x) &= \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2x}} J_{n+\frac{1}{2}}(x), \\
> y_n(x) &= \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2x}} Y_{n+\frac{1}{2}}(x). [1]''
> \end{align}

**Question**

I want to solve the Helmholtz equation in spherical coordinates  too. However, I want to solve the equation terms of an unknown number $\lambda$ that is not necessarily of integer (or half-integer value). What are eigenfunctions and eigenvalue of the Equation 1?
$$x^2 \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} + 2x \frac{dy}{dx} + \left(x^2 - \lambda\right) y = 0.\tag{1}$$

**My second attempt**

In my second attempt, I use the integral form of the bessel-function of the first king. This seems be bare better fruit.

$$J_\alpha(x) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\pi \cos(\alpha\tau - x \sin\tau)\,d\tau - \frac{\sin \alpha\pi}{\pi} \int_0^\infty e^{-x \sinh t - \alpha t} \, dt.$$

$$j_\alpha(x) = c\,x^{-1/2} \left[\int_0^\pi \cos(\alpha\tau - x \sin\tau)\,d\tau - \frac{\sin \alpha\pi}{\pi} \int_0^\infty e^{-x \sinh t - \alpha t} \, dt.\right]$$
I take the partial for the first time with the result being
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial{j_\alpha(x)} }{\partial{x}} 
&= 
-\frac{c}{2}\,
x^{-3/2} \left[\int_0^\pi \cos(\alpha\tau - x \sin\tau)\,d\tau - \frac{\sin \alpha\pi}{\pi} \int_0^\infty e^{-x \sinh t - \alpha t} \, dt.\right]
\\
&+
c\,x^{-1/2} \left[
\int_0^\pi 
 \sin\tau\, \sin(\alpha\tau - x \sin\tau)  \,d\tau 
+ 
\frac{\sin \alpha\pi}{\pi} 
\int_0^\infty 
\,\sinh(t)  \, e^{-x \sinh( t) - \alpha t}
 \, dt\right].
\end{align*}
I take the partial for a second time with the result being
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial^2{j_\alpha(x)} }{\partial{x}^2} 
&= 
-\frac{c}{2}\,
x^{-3/2} \left[
\int_0^\pi \sin(\tau)\,\sin(\alpha\tau - x \sin\tau)
\,d\tau 
+ 
\frac{\sin \alpha\pi}{\pi} 
\,
\int_0^\infty \sinh(t)\,e^{-x \sinh t - \alpha t} 
\, dt.
\right]
\\
&+ 
\frac{3\,c}{4}\,
x^{-5/2} \left[
\int_0^\pi \cos(\alpha\tau - x \sin\tau)
\,d\tau 
- 
\frac{\sin \alpha\pi}{\pi} 
\,
\int_0^\infty e^{-x \sinh t - \alpha t} 
\, dt.
\right]
\\
&+
c\,x^{-1/2} 
\left[
- \int_0^\pi 
\sin^2\tau\, \cos(\alpha\tau - x \sin\tau)  
\,d\tau 
-
\frac{\sin \alpha\pi}{\pi} 
\int_0^\infty 
\,\sinh^2(t)  \, e^{-x \sinh( t) - \alpha t}
\,dt
 \right].
\\
&-
\frac{c}{2}\,x^{-3/2} 
\left[
\int_0^\pi 
\sin\tau\, \sin(\alpha\tau - x \sin\tau)  
\,d\tau 
+ 
\frac{\sin \alpha\pi}{\pi} 
\int_0^\infty 
\,\sinh(t)  \, e^{-x \sinh( t) - \alpha t}
\,dt
 \right].
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
0 
&=
x^2\,
\frac{\partial^2{  u{(x)}  }}{\partial{x}^2}
+
2\,x \,
\frac{\partial{  u{(x)}  }}{\partial{x}}
  +
\left[
x^2
+  \lambda\right]\,u {(x)}
\end{align*}
Thus, upon re-organizing some more allows me to rewrite as
\begin{align*}
0 
&=
x^{+3/2} 
\left[
 \int_0^\pi  \cos^2(\tau )
\, \cos(\alpha\tau - x \sin\tau)  
\,d\tau 
-
\frac{\sin \alpha\pi}{\pi} 
\int_0^\infty 
\,  \cosh^2(t)   \, e^{-x \sinh( t) - \alpha t}
\,dt
 \right].
\\
&+  
x^{1/2} \left[
\int_0^\pi \sin(\tau)\,\sin(\alpha\tau - x \sin\tau)
\,d\tau 
+ 
\frac{\sin \alpha\pi}{\pi} 
\,
\int_0^\infty \sinh(t)\,e^{-x \sinh t - \alpha t} 
\, dt.
\right]
\\
&+
\left[\lambda
- 
 \frac{1 }{4}\right]\,
x^{-1/2} \left[
\int_0^\pi \cos(\alpha\tau - x \sin\tau)
\,d\tau 
- 
\frac{\sin \alpha\pi}{\pi} 
\,
\int_0^\infty e^{-x \sinh t - \alpha t} 
\, dt.
\right]
\end{align*}
It is likely that if I integrate by parts twice sequentially, and the second integral by parts once, then I will have solved this problem. But I am out of time for now.

**My first attempt**

Going off of what I have understood from above, I try the following test function for $y$:
$$y = c\,x^{-1/2}\, J_{n+\frac{1}{2}}(x) $$

\begin{align*}
0
&=
x^2\,
\frac{\partial^2{ \left[c\,x^{-1/2}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m! \Gamma(m+\alpha+1)} {\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}^{2m+\alpha}\right] }}{\partial{x}^2}
\\
&+
2\,x \,
\frac{\partial{   \left[c\,x^{-1/2}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m! \Gamma(m+\alpha+1)} {\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}^{2m+\alpha}\right]  }}{\partial{x}} 
\\
&+
\left[
x^2
+  \lambda\right]\,c\,x^{-1/2}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m! \Gamma(m+\alpha+1)} {\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}^{2m+\alpha}
\end{align*}
Continuing
\begin{align*}
0
&=
+\frac{-1}{2}x^2\,
\frac{\partial { \left[c\,x^{-3/2}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m! \Gamma(m+\alpha+1)} {\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}^{2m+\alpha}\right] }}{\partial{x} }
\\
&+
x^2\,
\frac{\partial { \left[c\,x^{-1/2}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{2m+\alpha}{2}\,\frac{(-1)^m}{m! \Gamma(m+\alpha+1)} {\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}^{2m+\alpha-1}\right] }}{\partial{x} }
\\
&+
\frac{-1}{2}\,2\,x \,
   \left[c\,x^{-3/2}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m! \Gamma(m+\alpha+1)} {\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}^{2m+\alpha}\right]  
\\
&+
2\,x \,
  \left[c\,x^{-1/2}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(2m+\alpha)}{2}\,\frac{(-1)^m}{m! \Gamma(m+\alpha+1)} {\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}^{2m+\alpha-1}\right]    
\\
&+
\left[
x^2
+  \lambda\right]\,c\,x^{-1/2}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m! \Gamma(m+\alpha+1)} {\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}^{2m+\alpha}
\end{align*}
Contiuing
\begin{align*}
0
&=
\frac{-1}{2}\frac{-3}{2}x^2\,
 \left[c\,x^{-5/2}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m! \Gamma(m+\alpha+1)} {\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}^{2m+\alpha}\right] 
\\
&+
\frac{-1}{2}x^2\,
  \left[c\,x^{-3/2}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{2m+\alpha}{2}\frac{(-1)^m}{m! \Gamma(m+\alpha+1)} {\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}^{2m+\alpha}\right] 
\\
&+
x^2\,\frac{-1}{2}
  \left[c\,x^{-3/2}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{2m+\alpha}{2}\,\frac{(-1)^m}{m! \Gamma(m+\alpha+1)} {\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}^{2m+\alpha-1}\right]
\\
&+
x^2\,
  \left[c\,x^{-1/2}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{2m+\alpha-1}{2}\,\frac{2m+\alpha}{2}\,\frac{(-1)^m}{m! \Gamma(m+\alpha+1)} {\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}^{2m+\alpha-1}\right]  
\\
&+
\frac{-1}{2}\,2\,x \,
   \left[c\,x^{-3/2}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m! \Gamma(m+\alpha+1)} {\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}^{2m+\alpha}\right]  
\\
&+
2\,x \,
  \left[c\,x^{-1/2}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(2m+\alpha)}{2}\,\frac{(-1)^m}{m! \Gamma(m+\alpha+1)} {\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}^{2m+\alpha-1}\right]    
\\
&+
\left[
x^2
+  \lambda\right]\,\left[c\,x^{-1/2}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m! \Gamma(m+\alpha+1)} {\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}^{2m+\alpha}\right]
\end{align*}
Simplifying:
\begin{align*}
0
&=
 \frac{ 3}{4} \,
 \left[c\,x^{-1/2}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m! \Gamma(m+\alpha+1)} {\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}^{2m+\alpha}\right] 
\\
&+
\frac{-1}{2}x\,
  \left[c\,x^{-1/2}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{2m+\alpha}{2}\frac{(-1)^m}{m! \Gamma(m+\alpha+1)} {\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}^{2m+\alpha}\right] 
\\
&+
-
  \left[c\,x^{-1/2}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{2m+\alpha}{2}\,\frac{(-1)^m}{m! \Gamma(m+\alpha+1)} {\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}^{2m+\alpha}\right]
\\
&+
2\,x \,
  \left[c\,x^{-1/2}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{2m+\alpha-1}{2}\,\frac{2m+\alpha}{2}\,\frac{(-1)^m}{m! \Gamma(m+\alpha+1)} {\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}^{2m+\alpha }\right]  
\\
&+
\frac{-1}{2}\,2 \,
   \left[c\,x^{-1/2}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m! \Gamma(m+\alpha+1)} {\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}^{2m+\alpha}\right]  
\\
&+
4\, 
  \left[c\,x^{-1/2}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(2m+\alpha)}{2}\,\frac{(-1)^m}{m! \Gamma(m+\alpha+1)} {\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}^{2m+\alpha }\right]    
\\
&+
\left[
x^2
+  \lambda\right]\,\left[c\,x^{-1/2}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m! \Gamma(m+\alpha+1)} {\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}^{2m+\alpha}\right]
\end{align*}
Simplifying more:
\begin{align*}
0
&=
\left[ x^2
+  \lambda - \frac{ 1}{4}  \right]\,
 \left[c\,x^{-1/2}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m! \Gamma(m+\alpha+1)} {\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}^{2m+\alpha}\right] 
\\
&+
\left[3- \frac{ 1}{2}x\right]\,
  \left[c\,x^{-1/2}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{2m+\alpha}{2}\frac{(-1)^m}{m! \Gamma(m+\alpha+1)} {\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}^{2m+\alpha}\right] 
\\
&+
2\,x \,
  \left[c\,x^{-1/2}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{2m+\alpha-1}{2}\,\frac{2m+\alpha}{2}\,\frac{(-1)^m}{m! \Gamma(m+\alpha+1)} {\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}^{2m+\alpha }\right]  
\end{align*}
Simplifying more more:
\begin{align*}
0
&=
\left[ x^2
+  \lambda - \frac{ 1}{4}  \right]\,
 \left[c\,x^{-1/2}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m! \Gamma(m+\alpha+1)} {\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}^{2m+\alpha}\right] 
\\
&+
\left[  \frac{4- x}{4}\right]\,
  \left[c\,x^{-1/2}\sum_{m=0}^\infty (2m+\alpha)\frac{(-1)^m}{m! \Gamma(m+\alpha+1)} {\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}^{2m+\alpha}\right] 
\\
&+
\frac{1}{2}\,x \,
  \left[c\,x^{-1/2}\sum_{m=0}^\infty  (2m+\alpha ) \, (2m+\alpha) \,\frac{(-1)^m}{m! \Gamma(m+\alpha+1)} {\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}^{2m+\alpha }\right]  
\end{align*}

I have this $x^2$ term that I would like to cancel out. If I could do that, then I would have the eigenvalues. I have tried a few approaches  without avail. I am not even sure if this effort would bare fruit.

Looking for a bit of help.

**Bibliography**

[1] Wikipedia contributors. (2021, February 7). Bessel function. In Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia. Retrieved 23:05, February 7, 2021, from https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Bessel_function&oldid=1005472771

[2] [Modified Helmholtz for imaginary constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3105583/modified-helmholtz-for-imaginary-constant)